# Spring MVC Controller method definition control

Tags: java, spring-mvc, architecture

Upfront, I am new to Spring MVC. I have used Struts2 quite a lot and probably, due to that, I am struggling a little in Spring MVC controller method definitions.

As I read in documentation, you can have [variety of type of possible parameter's - actually 20 - defined](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-arguments) in to Spring MVC controller method as well as you can return [variety of return types - actually 9 - back](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-return-types). And based on this, Spring MVC will act *accordingly*.

While this may offer a great flexibility, architect in me is trying to define some rules or restrictions so that my team does not need to get bogged down by extra-flexible rules!

I was hoping to get some restrictions defined to control variety of coding by variety of people. I was thinking of writing some kind of marker interfaces for my controllers.. something in the lines of [xxxAware interfaces](http://struts.apache.org/2.3.3/struts2-core/apidocs/org/apache/struts2/interceptor/package-summary.html) from Struts2..

Or may be something similar exists already in Spring MVC and I just don't know yet. Or may be outside in open source domain.

Looking for your suggestions. How you got your hands around flexibility offered by Spring MVC?

Comment: Have you considered code review?

Comment: @DavidGrant, yes. But, code review is a post processing (since developers have already coded things). I was hoping something more structural which can be injected compile time to assist my developers.